# Number of real solution of expression containing definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

> Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $$\displaystyle \int^{b}_af(x)\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\pi\right)\,dx=\int^b_af(x)\cos\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\pi\right)\,dx=0.$$

> Then number of solution of $f(x)=0$ in $(a,b)$ is

Let we assume $\displaystyle g(x)=\int^b_a f(x)\sin\bigg(\frac{x-a}{b-x}\pi\bigg)dx$

Then $\displaystyle g(a)=0$ and $g(b)=0$

Then here using rolles Theorem

There exists at least one real $x$ for which $g'(x)=0$ where $x\in (a,b)$

I did not understand how I find minimum number of roots for $f(x)=0$ in $(a,b)$

Please have a look on my problem

Comment: Reduce to the case $a=0, b=\pi$ just to make the notation easier.

Comment: $f$ can be identically $0.$

Comment: $g$ absolutely cannot be a function in $x$, since $x$ is a silent variable defined in the integrale

Comment: There is no question here. The sentence "Then number of ... is" might have been meant as a question, but if so, it should start with a question word like "What is the number of..." and end with a question mark (?)

Comment: Moreover, this implicit question is different from the final one, which is about the *minimum* number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $ f(x) $ has at least two real roots in $ (0,\pi) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247385/prove-that-fx-has-at-least-two-real-roots-in-0-pi)

Comment: Also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1286291/42969.